# How to replace value in XML tags when node have multiple values using JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I need to replace the values of the sEmployee and sWUnumber (Highlighted in yellow above)

So far what i can do is replace the node value and other attributes. But when in  tags. I cannot seem to replace the sEmployee and SWUnumber. I assume that these elements are not attributes?

Heres what i have done so far.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(Constant.Path_OldXmlFile);

    // Get Employee ID, I'm getting my values in excel data so don't mind this
    String sNewEmployeeID = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow,
            Constant.Personnel_NewEmployeeID);

    // Get Work Unit Number, I'm getting my values in excel data so don't mind this
    String sWorkUnitNumber = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow,
            Constant.Personnel_WorkUnit);
```

Comment: Get the `Node` `BODID`, get it's value, use a simple `String#replace` and then set the new value back to the `Node` and save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xPath to query the document for the node your after and replace it's text content, for example

```
try {
    // Load the document
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document original = b.parse(...);

    // Surgically locate the node you're after
    String expression = "/SyncPersonnel/ApplicationArea/BODID";
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(original, XPathConstants.NODE);
    // Get the nodes current text content
    String value = node.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(value);

    // Replace the values
    value = value.replace("sEmployee", "BananaMan").replace("sWUnumber", "007");
    // Set the text content with the new value
    node.setTextContent(value);

    // Save the new document
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(original);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(os);
        tf.transform(domSource, sr);

        String text = new String(os.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(text);

    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException | DOMException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncPersonnel>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <BODID>...-nid:LSAPPS:3004::sEmployee:0?Personnel&amp;verb=Sync&amp;workunit=sWUnumber</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>  
</SyncPersonnel>
```

the above code will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SyncPersonnel>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <BODID>...-nid:LSAPPS:3004::BananaMan:0?Personnel&amp;verb=Sync&amp;workunit=007</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>  
</SyncPersonnel>
```

Comment: @user3713453 It's a relatively basic/cut down version, but should give you something to work from

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks for this. Tagging as Answered.